CORS policy errors while deploying my app to cloud
I have tried to deploy my webapp to aws VM, after creating the vm and installing tomcat , when I deployed it i got this errors on the developper tools on chrome
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080' from origin 'http://' has been blocked by CORS policy: The request client is not a secure context and the resource is in more-private address space local.
I try the Allow-CORS extension of chrome but doesn't help me ! also i added those headers to my api but still encountering the same problem
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
Any suggestions please ?

Does this answer your question? has been blocked by CORS policy: The request client is not a secure context and the resource is in more-private address space local

The common CORS errors.
When you send a request using a webbrowser, try opening the network tab in the developer tools and inspect what happens. Usually you will see 2 requests being send to your endpoint.

A preflight request which has a request type of OPTIONS.
Your expected request, probably a GET or a POST or something.

When the OPTIONS request is send by the client, the goal is to establish an agreement with the server on whether or not that client can access the data it is requesting. This is done through Access-Control headers you have mentioned in the question. The server will send back a response to the client which contains the level of access control is allows.
A common mistake is that those headers are send back only on the regular requests (GET, POST etc.) and not during the preflight (OPTIONS) request.
My suggestion to you:
Add an endpoint handler to your service that handles incoming OPTIONS requests. Depending on your implementation you may have build-in framework support for this.
Example code for express:
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

// Middleware to handle CORS preflight requests
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS, HEAD');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'header1, header2...');

    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
        return res.sendStatus(200);
    }

    // Pass the request to the next middleware/function
    next();
});

// Example route
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});

Let me know if this helped!

Do i need to add this code into my doGet method in the api ?

It totally depends on whether your framework/library uses specific handler for http methods or they are all send to a single method.
If your doGet method is only executed when receiving a HTTP GET Request, then the answer is no, and you need to create a separate handler for HTTP OPTION Request or a middleware.
However, if your doGet method is executed on any HTTP request coming in at a given path than yes, use an if statement like i did with if (req.method === 'OPTIONS')

The error the OP presented doesn't suggest this is strictly a preflight issue. If it were, we surely have duplicates for that.

Sorry but this doesn't solve my problem :(
